# In Windows is there a way to trap signals on a Worker thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals

In Windows on a **Worker thread** after registering signals if I call some MAV code the signals are not being trapped.

```
void RegisterSignals()
{
    typedef void (*SignalHandlerPointer)(int);

    SignalHandlerPointer previousHandler;
    previousHandler = signal(SIGSEGV, SignalHandler);
    ... // Registering other signals   
}

void BadFunc () 
{
  int *ptr = nullptr;
  *ptr = 45;
}
```

Since the application is a multi threaded environment and I have used MSDN Thread APIs I tried even registering signals for each thread but even that doesn't work out.

Is there any way so that the signals get trapped? Could anyone help me in this?

All comments and suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Are you really going to try and capture `SIGSEGV` in another thread by using a Windows equivalent to `sigwait()`?  That's fundamentally broken.  What will the thread that generated the `SIGSEGV` do if it's not interrupted by a signal?  Spin away generating an infinite series of `SIGSEGV` signals until the process dies.

Comment: I don't think Windows sends `SIGSEGV` signal on segmentation faults like Unix does. Instead, Windows has the concept of [structured exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-170), that **can** be caught a bit like C++ exceptions (in the same thread). But I wouldn't try to catch segmentation errors: just fix the bug.

Comment: @prapin [Windows *can* send `SIGSEGV` "signals" that processes can catch using the `signal()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/signal?view=msvc-170).  I suspect it's implemented internally using structured exceptions.  And yes, this does look like a misguided attempt to paper over a bug.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Currently I am registering signals only once. The purpose of calling BadFunc is just to check if any unknown MAV occurs later whether our own SignalHandler function is being called for free up the memory and close any Handles if opened. It gets trapped in Windows when we are on main thread but on worker thread that doesn't get trapped

Answer (score 0):

`signal(SIGSEGV, ...)` doesn't work like that on Windows. On Windows, `std::signal` works in cooperation with `std::raise`. You can't raise a signal by using Undefined Behavior.

At the OS level, Windows uses Structured Exception Handling (SEH), which is unrelated to C++. The Microsoft Structured Exception that will happen here is an `AccessViolation(0xC0000005)`.

Comment: In the codebase there might occur a chance where we don't know where this MAV signal exception occurs. I think std::raise is an explicit way of calling our signal handler.